# Как округлить 0.5 в меньшую сторону, а 0.5000001 - в большую

Tags: java, kotlin, округление

Я знаю про `Math.round(n)`, но мне нужно чтобы 0.5 округляло в 0 (`1.5 -> 1`, `2.5 -> 2`), а например 0.50000001 уже округляло в 1 (`1.50001 -> 2`, `2.5001 -> 3`).
Язык Kotlin или Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для вашей задачи можно воспользоваться классом [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), который используется для более сложных ситуаций с округлением (вроде вашей).

Для решения вашей задачи:

1. Создадим объект класса `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("0.5");
```

2. Задаём правило для округления. В примере `0` - количество цифр после запятой, `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` - то, округление которое вы и желали получить: если оба соседних числа равноудалены (то есть дробная часть 5 десятых), то округление произойдёт в сторону 0, если же числа не равноудалены, то округление произойдёт по принципу "где ближе".

```
number = number.setScale(0, ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

И так, что вышло в итоге:

```
BigDecimal number1 = new BigDecimal("0.5");
BigDecimal number2 = new BigDecimal("0.50000001");

number1 = number1.setScale(0, ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //0
number2 = number2.setScale(0, ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //1
```

Answer (score 9):

А как насчёт простого:

```java
-Math.round(-n);
```

Comment: Отличная мысль!

Comment: А что означает - перед Math  (`-Math`)? Я имею ввиду минус перед Math. а не перед n.

Comment: @Зонтик то же самое что и перед n. Унарный минус.

Answer (score -2):

Еще как вариант, можно от числа перед округлением отнимать малое значение, которое заведомо меньше точности. Что-то типа:

```
println(Math.round(1.5 - 0.000000001))        // 1
println(Math.round(1.50000001 - 0.000000001)) // 2
```

**Disclaimer**
Этот метод работает на числах с заранее известной точностью и не является универсальным для всех математических операций.

```
println(Math.round(1.5000000001 - 0.0000000001)) // 2
println(Math.round(100000000.5 - 0.01))          // 100000000
```

Comment: Будет привирать для маленьких целых. Не будет работать для больших целых.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не вижу связи. Можно пример или подробности?

Comment: `1.5000000001` будет округлен к `1.0` - ошибка для маленьких целых. `100000000.5` будет округлен к `100000001` - ошибка для больших целых.

Comment: Для первого случая я же написал что "отнимать малое значение, которое заведомо меньше точности", для второго уже идет потеря точности. Я понял, дополню ответ.